# Can't get Symfony validation to work

Tags: php, symfony, validation

I am trying to add some validation for my registration form, but i can't get it to work, so far i have added my User entity

Snippet.

```
class User {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
   protected $userid;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
 */
 protected $username;
```

For this i've added a validation.yml to my bundle.

```
# src/Blomster/UserBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml

Blomster/UserBundle/Entity/User:
    properties:
        username:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - MinLength: { limit: 3, message: "Username is too short." }
            - MaxLength: { limit: 15, message: "Username is too long." }
```

Using $form->isValid() always return true, so i tried to var_dump my form

```
      'validation_groups' => null
      'validation_constraint' => null
      'constraints' => 
        array (size=0)
          ...
```

The form itself is working great, it adds to my data base when submitted, do i need to add the constraints to the form somehow?

Added UserType.php

```
class UserType extends AbstractType {

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('username', null, array('label' => 'Username'));
    $builder->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'Email'));
    $builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
        'type' => 'password',
        'required' => true,
        'first_options' => array('label' => 'Password'),
        'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat password'),
      ));
  }

  public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
    return array('data_class' => 'Blomster\UserBundle\Entity\User');
  }

  public function getName() {
    return 'user';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a length limit :

```
        - MinLength: { limit: 3 }
        - MaxLength: { limit: 15 }
```

[here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/MinLength.html) is the documentation.

In fact : you need to specify a limit because you can also set other options like a message and so on.

Comment: I've added your corrections, however, it still doesn't add the constraints to the form. I've updated the question.

Comment: Is this necessary when running on dev env? Did't work thought :/

Comment: Nope, but I easily get caching problems using APC (which persists even if you're in DEV), so after all my config changes, svn updates and so on, I clean all (apc / app/cache) caches.

Comment: I have doubts in fact. Can you check in your config.yml if you don't have something like `validation: { enable_annotations: true }`, in such a case it is possible that validation takes his length parameters from the entity itself.

Comment: I've tried to turn apc off, excluding this is a cache porblem. :) The enable_annotations:true is presence in my confnig.yml. Could this be form related, somehow?

Comment: I do think no, but maybe the doctrine annotation `@ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)` may specify to the validation that the max size of your string is 30.

Comment: The form max length seem to be 30, but if remove the limit and enter 50 chars, is still goes thought the isValid(). Its like it don't even read my validation.yml.

Comment: Okey so lets try with annotations: `@Assert\MaxLength(15)` and `@Assert\MinLength(3)` below `@ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)`.

Comment: (do not forget to `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;`)

Comment: Alright, first of all i used / instead of \ in my yaml. However my issue would seem that my RegistrationType embeds my UserType form, and therefor it wants to validate RegistrationType instead. Which you were unaware of. Gonna go with your answer tho, as it was helpfull. Thank you.